# latex: Can I create a link to "References" section?

Tags: hyperlink, reference, latex, cross-reference, bibliography

I am using *thebibliography* environment for putting a few references; manually and not using Bibtex.
Is there a way to create a hyper link from text to jump to the top of the References?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Reviewed record documents \cite{dailyConstructionNotes}


\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem {dailyNotes} Daily  Reports.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load the `hyperref` package, all your `\cite` commands will automatically create a link to the bibliography.

If you explicitly want to jump to the top of the References, you could add an hypertarget:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Reviewed record documents \cite{dailyNotes}

\hyperlink{foo}{top of bibliography}

\newpage

\hypertarget{foo}{}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem {dailyNotes} Daily  Reports.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```